# Perforce - Get the differences for a particular changelist

Tags: perforce, changelist

How can i get list of files and the differences (with color highlighting) from a changelist so that I can send it for peer review.

I tried in windows cmd `p4 describe #changelist` however it just shows the list of files opened in the changelist.

*[Update] I could find `p4 diff` and it gives the differences in all the changelists in a command prompt.*

I was hoping for a batch file which could input a changelist number as parameter and generate a code review which i can share over email.

*sorry, I am new to perforce and don't know what to lookup so I have'nt tried anything.*

Answer (score 2):

I see you're trying to send changes to your peers for review, and you're interested in things like color highlighting of changes, etc.

Don't try to build a code review system from scratch, yourself.

Instead, start with a code review system that is already built; there are a number of them already out there, both free and commercial.

You can start with something like Perforce Swarm, or P4Web, or the Perforce review daemon, all of which are included with Perforce, and you can just ask your sysadmin to install them.

Or there are plenty of other fine code review tools for Perforce that you can find.

But building a tool from scratch is a big project, and you probably have many other better things to do.

Comment: Not exactly a code review system, but something that just helps me get a clean output (I can copy from clipboard and paste in email client) with color highlighting. At work, we have started using perforce however for peer review we do screen sharing which is kind of an overkill. Thanks for your reply, I will try to research more on the code review tools for perforce.

Answer (score 1):

```
p4 describe #change
```

Should print out the diffs of the files, in a format you can control with the `-d<flags>` option.

the `-s` option turns off those diffs.

If you want a tool to review pre-commit changes, you could use [ReviewBoard](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.5/users/tools/post-review/) which we set up a one point. post-review can take local changes and post them for review.

Comment: This doesn't work for pending changes, and also note that `p4 describe` won't print diffs for deleted or added files.

Comment: And `p4 diff ...` can do (sort of) generate diffs for a pending change (if it's the only one in your client), but it has the same issue with added/deleted files.